# SNOWFLAKE- Trying to run task on 2nd Tuesday of every month (USING CRON 0 15 8-14 * 2 UTC)- running for all days 8-14? Why?

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I am trying to run the Snowflake task on the 2nd Tuesday of every month using (USING CRON 0 15 8-14 * 2 UTC). But it is running for all the days between 8-14. Why this behavior? Is this a known issue in snowflake?

Comment: You need to add some bash script to know the 2nd Tuesday of the month

Answer (score 1):

there are plenty of online cron generators that will create cron strings for you.

This string should do what you want:

0 0 15 ? 1/1 TUE#2 *

Comment: This error is coming when I am using # in snowflake tasks
create or replace task <task-name>
 warehouse= <WH-name>
 schedule='USING CRON 08 21 * * TUE#2 UTC'

Invalid schedule was specified. Please refer to the docs on what constitutes a valid schedule.

Comment: Snowflake documentation says it only supports a subset of cron syntax, so I’m guessing it doesn’t support what you want to be able to do

Comment: I think I agree with you @NickW.